# Select by Location multiple layers using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, select-by-location, error-000840

Using ArcMap 10.3, I would like to Select By Location multiple layers using ArcPy. The error message states line 7 is not correct. I can't find the error though. "Water_Body_Boundary" is my source layer.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
bldgLayer = "Water_Body_Boundary"
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name != bldgLayer:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(layer, "WITHIN", bldgLayer)
```

The error message:

> Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 7, in  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7359, in SelectLayerByLocation raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer. Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation)

Answer (score 3):

As @BERA suggested you'll need to reference a feature layer in the select layer by location method, use this statement before the select statement:

```
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name != bldgLayer:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer, "featureLayer")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("featureLayer", "WITHIN", bldgLayer)
```